# VSCode(Vetur) does not recognize customized Vue property in component

Tags: typescript, vue.js, visual-studio-code, vue-component, intellisense

I've mounted a plugin on Vue in a main.ts file, declared its type in a plugin.d.ts file, then used it in a component.vue file. The compilation works fine, but VSCode intellisense still tells me this property does not exist. Am I missing anything?
Here are the codes.

```
//plugin.ts
import Vue as _Vue from 'vue'
export class Plugin { 
  someFunc() { //do something } 
}
const plugin = new Plugin()
export default function myPlugin(Vue: typeof _Vue) {
  Vue.prototye.$plugin = plugin
}
```

and for declaration,

```
//plugin.d.ts
import { Plugin } from './plugin'
declare module 'vue/types/vue' {
  interface Vue {
    $plugin: Plugin
  }
}
```

then I mount it in an entry point,

```
//main.ts
import Vue from 'vue'
import plugin from './plugin'

Vue.use(plugin)
```

finally, I want to use the plugin in a component,

```
//component.vue
import { Component, Vue } from 'vue-proprety-decorator'
@Component
export default class MyComponnent extends Vue {
  func() {
    this.$plugin.someFunc()
  }
}
```

The compilation shows no problem, but intellisense tells me "Property '$plugin' does not exist on type 'MyComponent'." and autocompletion does not work.

Did I do anything wrong?

Answer (score 2):

Try to change the name of the type definition from plugin.d.ts to types.d.ts .
That did the trick for me.

Comment: Thanks so much.. i've used "Augmenting Types for Use with Plugins" + your tip and it worked perfectly